# What to do about questions that are much more general and timeless than their tags or titles?

Tags: discussion

Let's assume, there is an existing, old question where the OP is posing the question for a **concrete version** (via tag, title or in the question). Or with some other **specifics** (like SQL Server instead of the more general [vanilla SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714461/ansi-sql-manual)).

The answers are general and would apply to other versions and more general cases. So they might be useful to other people as well. Which doesn't mean they may become outdated some day, but not yet.

**Example:** [Update every rows with a value from another column from same table SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13929158/1)<sup>1</sup>

- **tag:** [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), but answer(s) valid for (most) any SQL
- **asked:** 2012, but answer(s) still valid

Let's now assume, there are numerous of these.

What is the best approach here?

- **Add the more general tag** ("sql" tag in my example): Is not desctructive, takes merely a few
  seconds.
- **Remove the specific tag** ("sql-server-2008" tag)
- **Stay the hell away** from these posts: Editing or retagging the question would most likely make it a duplicate and then what?
- **Stay calm**, happy and in eternal bliss and spend your time on more useful things
- **Downvote it** as it is way old (tag: "sql-server-2008", wtf!)
- **Flag it as dup**

______
<sub><sup>1</sup> It has been edited in the meantime, the linked revision reflects the state of the question at the time of posing this question.</sub>

Comment: SQL Server 2008 old? I remember learning about some whiz-bang new DBMS coming out soon - SQL Server 2005! Wow I'm old....

Comment: @RobertColumbia next new thing is SQL Serverless ...

Comment: Bullets 1 and 2, both.

Comment: Does bullet 4 involve pizza?

Comment: Not if the pizza is cold.

Comment: Seriously though, not for the linked example but for other questions removing the specific tag and rephrasing them as more general would probably make them a dup.

Comment: I lot of people do use SQL server 2008. Also, it is not a valid reason to downvote something because you aren't benefitting from it. If it was helpful to others in past, and if it is not relevant anymore, you might suggest that the content is updated to reflect the changes to the platform. You might also want to remove "2008" from the title if it is a generic question. But since your changes will be reviewed by others, make sure to mention your reasoning in the edit summary.

Comment: Age is a *really* poor reason to downvote something; it is at best a reason not to vote on something. Vote based on quality. There may be something else that we need to do with content that has aged away, but if that is the case then a separate mechanism needs to be designed for it, it will have nothing to do with the quality voting system.

Answer (score 21):

I would add the more general tag, and then stay calm.

There are going to be cases where something that worked in [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) may not work in [sql-server-2030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2030), so leaving both on there gives more context as to when a question and the answers were valid.

It also gives those who answer hints as to what kind of answers the user is expecting (ie, in this case the user won't be interested in [sql-server-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-1.0) answers).

If it is a duplicate (that is, an answer that works in an older/newer version also applied to this version) then I think that flagging it as duplicate is the right thing to do as well, perhaps with a comment explaining that nothing has changed so the question asker doesn't think it was an accident...

Answer (score 2):

For the peculiar case of SQL, I recommend staying away from the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag, unless maybe your question is about the SQL standard. There's almost nothing without specific quirks in each DBMS. The tag itself even insists you name your specific DBMS because of this. Sometimes the quirks are performance related, sometimes syntax related, a function that isn't built in or works a little differently, maybe even just conventions and norms and gotchas. Sure, there are common *concepts* that you can apply to all of them, but it's very rare that the nuances of the specific DMBS don't rear their ugly heads soon while implementing. Questions about the conceptual probably don't belong on SO; [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (formerly Programmers) is probably a better fit for those.

Comment: Yes, sql is probably a bad example for what I am asking here. And some things tend to get more complicated the longer you look at them. Sigh ...

Comment: @wirap Over my years as a programmer and a participant at SO, I've learned you have to be careful about generalizing. Finding the right levels of abstraction is very much a learned skill. ;) My gut instinct here is that your question is really addressing a set of situations that, in aggregate, can go any number of different ways depending on specifics. While "case by case" might be a bit overly simplistic approach, I think you've chosen much too high a level of generality.

Comment: @jmc26 I tend to agree. However getting some general pointers on how this site is intended to work is definitely helpful even if we can't solve my question here in a general one-fits-all way. It provides a better understanding is what it does.

Comment: I agree. I tend to think the `tsql` tag might be more appropriate than the `sql` tag for that question and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

Is "Update every rows with a value from another column from same table" even a task specific to SQL Server?

I'm sure most people will tell you "no". In fact, I did this just yesterday with a MariaDB server. In those cases, if a specific tidbit that doesn't alter the fundamental question, don't shy away about removing them. We remove irrelevant details about any question that we believe is more general and therefore more useful for a greater sample of users.

If the task is generic, having irrelevant information that doesn't change the answer is not useful.

Comment: What could be application-specific would be some transformation that is easy to do in some particular program, but harder in a standards-compliant manner. One hopes that the answers would mention the difference, and both ways of achieving the goal. However, the situation there might change, if some feature gets to a newer version of the standard or becomes more widely accepted...

Comment: The question's title is misleading here. The OP wants a part of one column as the value for the other. `SUBSTRING` works here for SQL Server, for Oracle it wouldn't. So I think the DBMS specific tag is justified here.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser then change the title...